# Show block depending on user group in volt, phalcon

Tags: php, phalcon

I'm in process of learning the Phalcon framework and for this period i have had one question. How can i show an block depending on user group in .volt template? In my template engine i could write something like this:

```
[group=guest]<div>You should register</div>[/group]
[group=user]<div>Welcome!</div>[/group]
```

I read about ACL component of Phalcon, but i want show user-group content in templates file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `{% if %}` blocks. Assume that you have the name of the group in a user object.

*Controller*

```
....
$this->view->setVar('user', $user);
....
```

*View*

```
{% if user.group == 'guest' %}
<div>You should register</div>
{% elseif user.group == 'user' %}
<div>Welcome {{ user.name }}</div>
{% else %}
<div>You should register</div>
{% endif %}
```